# pandas : sampling avoiding twice same values in different samples

Tags: python, pandas

I have this 5000 rows dataframe.

I want to make 4 random samples of 300 rows from the dataframe. I want each of my sample to have no duplicate inside the sample, but i also want no duplicate among samples. Ie i dont want a row to appear in sample 1 and sample 3 for example.

I have tried `df.sample(300,replace=False)` but it's not enough.

I have also searched the forum but didnt find what i want.

How can i code pandas to do so without doing batch groups?

Comment: Could you clarify how `df.sample(300,replace=False)` is "not enough"? What does it output, and what would b your expected output?

Comment: there is no option for recursive df.sample that doesnt take the same lines. you are only sure df.sample output doest have duplicates inside the output, not among recursive df.sample commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a pandas function specifically for that, but how about doing this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col": range(5000)})

sample = df.sample(1200, replace= False)

sample.duplicated().any()
>> False                    # <-- no duplicates

samples = [sample.iloc[i-300:i] for i in range(300, 1500, 300)] # <-- 4 samples
```

Considering that .sample will return a random selection without replacement, this would achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks, that fits perfectly even if there is not a built in function indeed